# How does @Secured know what role a user is from database?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I understand what @Secured DOES but not really sure HOW it does it.

Can someone explain how @Secured grabs the roles? Is it getting it from the `authorities-by-username-query`? Can I put any String in the params as long as it's in the database?

Comment: It it getting the roles from [`SecurityContext`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContext.html). User's roles are stored in security context during authentication process and they are retrieved for example using the `authorities-by-username-query` query you mention (depends on your exact configuration).

Comment: Ahhhh I see, Thank you very much. You could post that as an answer if you'd like and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User's roles are stored in `SecurityContext`, or to be more specific in `Authentication` object that is stored in the `SecurityContext`. When you authenticate, the authentication information is loaded and stored in the security context. The roles can originate from database, depending on your configuration. In your case they are loaded using `authorities-by-username-query` query.

When the security interceptor processes the authorization (for instance method-level authorization using `@Secured` annotation) it determines whether the user should be able to access it based on the Authentication stored in the context.

---

To better understand what happens under the hood, you should look at the *Spring Security Filter chain* and [Architecture section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#overall-architecture) of the reference guide.

Answer (score 1):

> SpringSecurity provides and awesome AOP way of securing methods in
>   Java Application by using @Secured. Spring logically ORs the roles
>   listed in @Secured annotation. The collection of GrantedAuthorities is obtained from `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()`

[AbstractSecurityInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/intercept/AbstractSecurityInterceptor.html) is the abstract class that implements
security interception for secure objects.

1. Obtain the Authentication object from the SecurityContextHolder.

   2. Determine if the request relates to a secured or public invocation
      by looking up the secure object request against the SecurityMetadataSource.
   3. For an invocation that is secured (there is a list of
      ConfigAttributes for the secure object invocation):

      - If either the Authentication.isAuthenticated() returns false, or the alwaysReauthenticate is true, authenticate the request against the configured AuthenticationManager. When authenticated, replace the Authentication object on the SecurityContextHolder with the returned value.
      - Authorize the request against the configured AccessDecisionManager.
      - Perform any run-as replacement via the configured RunAsManager.
      - Pass control back to the concrete subclass, which will actually proceed with executing the object. A InterceptorStatusToken is returned so that after the subclass has finished proceeding with execution of the object, its finally clause can ensure the AbstractSecurityInterceptor is re-called and tidies up correctly using finallyInvocation(InterceptorStatusToken).
      - The concrete subclass will re-call the AbstractSecurityInterceptor via the afterInvocation (InterceptorStatusToken, Object) method.
      - If the RunAsManager replaced the Authentication object, return the    SecurityContextHolder to the object that existed after the call to AuthenticationManager.
      - If an AfterInvocationManager is defined, invoke the invocation manager and allow it to replace the object due to be returned to the caller.

Look at the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/intercept/AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java) for more understanding.

> [AccessDecisionManager](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/c8f598778f3d45e0092385d20593ade6f33e138f/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/AccessDecisionManager.java) is the interface which is implemented as AffirmativeBased, ConsensusBased or UnanimousBased orchestrates the voters and asks each in turn whether the requesting user should be let through the @Secured annotation or denied.

Comment: Wow little bit more complicated that I thought. Thank you!